# Why is this opinion based?

Tags: support

Why on earth was  [Is there a reason GaN chargers stop at 65W?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/453887/27147) closed as opinion based when the answer given shows there *is* a technical answer! I am very well aware how StackExchange is in general newbie hostile but please.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there was deleted comments relevant to this, but the mod who helped close it has changed their mind about the question and reopened it 2 hours after this question was asked.

It is a borderline opinion question because the answers cant be factually or conclusively proven right or wrong. How or why an entire industry decides its engineering and marketing goals is enormously difficult to pinpoint an answer without a significant amount of speculation, short of a industry group flat out saying "we dont want n+ watt chargers because of x y z". Opinion based close votes typically follow questions like this.

That there may be regulatory barriers, or better market opportunities are good, logical guesses, but hardly non-opinion. Much better than other opinion answers like"aliens forbid them" but still opinion. And even then, those are not technical answers to a technical question. Those are business answers to a marketing question.

Comment: I personally dont feel this question is off topic enough to vote to close it in it's current state. Others are heavy handed in that regard.

Comment: I agree with you that barring a note in a reference design or something similar, answers will be primarily speculation. A minor correction, the close reason is "opinion based", not "off topic". I think it's a margin call either way, and I probably would have closed it without the answer.